# Log4j + Scala: How to log only my custom messages?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, logging, log4j

I have a Spark app (written in Scala) and the following code to log. 
I would like to log only my custom messages, not everything including Spark messages.

So far, I have the following code:

```
// creates pattern layout
var  layout = new PatternLayout()
var conversionPattern = "%-7p %d [%t] %c %x - %m%n"
layout.setConversionPattern(conversionPattern)

// creates console appender
var consoleAppender = new ConsoleAppender()
consoleAppender.setLayout(layout)
consoleAppender.activateOptions()

// creates file appender
var fileAppender = new FileAppender()
fileAppender.setFile("applog3.txt")
fileAppender.setLayout(layout)
fileAppender.activateOptions()

// configures the root logger
var rootLogger = Logger.getRootLogger
rootLogger.setLevel(Level.INFO)
rootLogger.addAppender(consoleAppender)
rootLogger.addAppender(fileAppender)

// creates a custom logger and log messages
var logger = Logger.getLogger(this.getClass())
logger.debug("this is a debug log message")
logger.info("this is a information log message")
logger.warn("this is a warning log message")
logger.trace("this is a TRACE log message")

if (arg.length < 8) {
  logger.error("=> wrong parameters number")
  System.err.println("Parameters ....")
  System.exit(1)
}
```

But I could see, not only my messages but others too which are related to Spark. For instance:

```
INFO    [task-result-getter-1] org.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskSetManager  - Finished task 1.0 in stage 5.0 (TID 6) in 631 ms on localhost (executor driver) (1/2)
```

The thing is I would like to see only my messages (info, errors, o whatever I wanted to log) and also the errors logged from Spark. How could I do this by code?

Answer (score 0):

Two things to note:

1. Set additivity of your custom logger to 'false'

`logger.setAdditivity(false)`

This will prevent logs from your customer logger from being repeated by parent loggers

2. Set root logger's log level to 'ERROR'

`rootLogger.setLevel(Level.ERROR)`

This will print only ERROR level logs from any package unless you have defined a custom logger for your package/class with different log level.

Since you have defined a custom logger for your class/package, then the above steps will result in the logs you expect.

Comment: Adding `logger.setAdditivity(false)`, I get this message: `log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.apache.spark.mllib.sampling.runROS$).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.`.